# Is it possible to access underlying data from Polars in cython?

Tags: python, cython, python-polars

Is there anyway to access the underlying structures in cython/c++ for polars?

I have a number of scripts that grab np.ndarrays and iterates.  Is there anything similar for polars?

Comment: Should be possible.  If it already exposes a byte interface that you can memoryview, should be able to decipher it pretty easily.  Otherwise go looking at what columnar format it has underneath. And make a c++ equivalent to the rust.

Comment: I  am not quite sure how to see the arrow data

Comment: It's arrow under the hood, but I don't see how to access natively

Answer (score 1):

It should definitely be possible. Polars memory can be exported to pyarrow zero copy. And then you can use arrow's [C data interface](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/CDataInterface.html) to get a hold of that memory.

Here is an example in the polars repo where they use the C data interface to get a hold of that memory again in Rust. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/tree/master/examples/python_rust_compiled_function

Comment: any idea how though?

Answer (score 1):

polars.DataFrame([1,2,3]).to_arrow() will get a table that can be modified
and edited.

```
 cimport pyarrow
 cimport pyarrow.lib
 from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr
 cdef  iterate_through_table(polars_obj):
     cdef:
         shared_ptr[pyarrow.CTable] table = pyarrow.lib.unwrap_table(polars_obj.to_arrow())
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying data structures for polars are C++ arrays. However, you can access them using the Python API. For example, to get the underlying data for a polar, you can use the `get_data()` method:

```py
polar = some_polar.get_data()
```

You can then iterate over the data using the `for` keyword:

```py
for x, y in polar:
    # do something with x and y
```

If you need to access the underlying C++ arrays directly, you can use the `get_cpp_array()` method:

```py
polar_array = some_polar.get_cpp_array()
```

You can then access the data using the `[]` operator:

```py
x = polar_array[0]
y = polar_array[1]
```

Comment: Create a new variable in the Python file that is the name of the C++ structure. 
You can then access the underlying structures through this new variable.

Comment: we can get pretty close.

```python
>>> from polars import Polar
>>> from ctypes import c_void_p, cast
>>> p = Polar(range(10), range(10))
>>> p.__array_interface__['data']
(10966272, False)
>>> cast(p.__array_interface__['data'][0], c_void_p).value
10966272
>>> p.as_ndarray().__array_interface__['data']
(10966272, False)
>>> cast(p.as_ndarray().__array_interface__['data'][0], c_void_p).value
10966272
```

Comment: So we can get the `ctypes.c_void_p` for the underlying memory address of a `polars.Polar` using the `__array_interface__` dictionary. We can then use `ctypes.cast` to convert this back to a Python `int`.

Keep in mind that `polars.Polar` is not a `numpy.ndarray`, so many of the methods and attributes that you would expect to work with `ndarray`s will not work with `Polar`s. However, you can always convert a `Polar` to an `ndarray` using the `as_ndarray` method.